# regular expression issue if string contain \n

Tags: regex, swift

I am trying to get the value of title using regular expression. whats wrong with this regular expression. match is coming nil.

```
 let strToCheck = "<title>youtube \n </title>"
 let rgx = "<title(.*?)>(.*?)</title>"

 let rx = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: rgx, options: [.caseInsensitive])

 if let match = rx.firstMatch(in: strToCheck, options: [], range: 
            NSMakeRange(0, string.characters.count)) {

  }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The original problem is because you did not escape `/` which makes you regex breaks. you need to add `\` before the slash as following:

```
<title(.*?)>(.*?)<\/title>
```

[Demo url](https://regex101.com/r/2EG88D/1)

As [Wiktor Stribiżew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3832970/wiktor-stribi%C5%BCew) explained in his comment below that Swift does not need to escape the slash I have updated the regex to match new line cases as following:

```
<title(.*?)>(?s).*?</title>
```

[Demo URL](https://regex101.com/r/2EG88D/7)

Note: In the demo there is a escape character for `/` but it's not necessary for Swift

Comment: There is absolutely no need escaping a forward slash in a swift regex pattern . The multiline flag only redefines the behavior of anchors that are not used here.

Comment: Oh i didn't know that about swift thanks for clarifying! , but i have updated my answer in order to match new line cases if its there

Comment: The update has not made the solution correct, this is an awful pattern. Please consider removing your wrong answer or fix. Do not ever use `(.|\n+)*?` - it is a great performance killer.

Comment: What about now ?

Comment: Now, much better.